# Weird shadow in jquery-ui modal dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using this code to create a modal dialog which is working fine:

```
var div = $('<div>');
        div.html('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sint utinam persecuti cu vel, ut his vero mazim omittantur. Assum tation ea quo. Nec at atqui nobis complectitur, dolores adipisci mei ad. Graeci rationibus referrentur ius te, eu regione pertinacia eum.  </p>  <p>Labores efficiendi in per, vix volumus nominati in. Mea id viris ludus impedit. Nec te eligendi aliquando reprimique, ut sea vidisse principes. Mei suas purto debitis te, erat veritus sit in. Ut nec elit nulla postulant, vix at aeque menandri voluptatibus.  </p>  <p>Qui erant iusto laudem et, ad omnes debitis albucius vim. Et pri discere insolens, partem evertitur ne sed. Id minim virtute sapientem duo, ne ipsum dignissim vulputate eam. Duo diceret volumus platonem ne.</p>');
        div.attr('title', 'Error!');
        div.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 340,
            width: 320,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            },
            buttons: {
                'Ok': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
```

...except for a strange shadow below the *title bar*. See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/99CEn/

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I remove the shadow?
2. How can I make the title bar red? (Possibly with an icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.ui-widget-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE !important;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/99CEn/1/

Comment: Thank you. But why is this happening? Shouldn't that shadow *not* be there in the first place?

Comment: Here was the problem for the shadow: .ui-widget-content {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% top #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #333333;
}

Answer (score 1):

Use below css

```
.ui-widget-header{
    background:red !important;
    border: red;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE !important;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    color: #333333;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/99CEn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can change these things in jquery-ui.css

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css

1. shadow ------>  .ui-widget-content{background:none !important;}
2. Title bar --->  .ui-widget-header{custom}